# How can I add a newline to the existing words being displayed?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have this line of code which's displaying a timer:

```
timerDisplay.innerHTML = days + "days " + hours + "hours " + minutes + "minutes " + seconds + "seconds ";
```

The problem is that it's appearing like so:

```
10days 12hours 34mins 20seconds
```

I want it to appear like so:

```
10   12    34      20
days hours minutes seconds
```

During my attempts, I've tried `\n` and `\r` as well `</br>` in front of and behind each word (days, hours, minutes, seconds) but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and `<span>`s and `<br />`

```js
const days = "05",
  hours = "08",
  minutes = "32",
  seconds = "11";

document.querySelector("#time").innerHTML = `
  <span>${days} <br /> days</span> 
  <span>${hours} <br/> hours</span>
  <span>${minutes}<br/> minutes</span> 
  <span>${seconds}<br/> seconds `;
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All whitespace (including `\n` and `\r`) in HTML is rendered as a single space. `</br>`is an invalid tag. The [`br`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-br-element) element is written with the `<br>` tag (`<br/>` in XHTML).

To get output like what you've described, though, you'd probably want a [`table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table for doing that. Inside JavaScript code, I create a template for the format that you want to show, and then, assign it to `div` that will show it.

```js
var days = 10;
var hours = 12;
var minutes = 34;
var seconds = 20;

var tableFormat = 
  '<table>' + 
   '<tr>' + 
    '<td>' + 
     '<label>' + days + '</label>' + 
    '</td>' + 
    '<td>' + 
     '<label>' + hours + '</label>' + 
    '</td>' + 
    '<td>' + 
     '<label>' + minutes + '</label>' + 
    '</td>' + 
    '<td>' + 
     '<label>' + seconds + '</label>' + 
    '</td>' + 
   '</tr>' + 
   '<tr>' + 
    '<td>' + 
     '<label>days</label>' + 
    '</td>' + 
    '<td>' + 
     '<label>hours</label>' + 
    '</td>' + 
    '<td>' + 
     '<label>minutes</label>' + 
    '</td>' + 
    '<td>' + 
     '<label>seconds</label>' + 
    '</td>' + 
   '</tr>' + 
  '</table>'

timerDisplay.innerHTML = tableFormat;
```

```html
<div id="timerDisplay"></div>
```